# Jquery remove,add and find query

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

In the following code,after removing the checkboxes and adding it again.The alert always becomes true for "could not find checkboxes"

```
<div id="r_n">   
    <div name="r_t"><input type="checkbox" name="r_name" />Name</div>
    <div name="r_t"><input type="checkbox" name="r_name" />Address</div>
    <div name="r_t"><input type="checkbox" name="r_name" />Value</div>
    <div name="r_t"><input type="checkbox" name="r_name" />Total</div>
</div>

 <script>
    $("r_t").remove();
    $("r_n").html('');
```

Now all the checkboxes are removed form the dom

```
$("r_n").append('<div name="r_t"><input type="checkbox" name="r_name" />Name</div>
             <div name="r_t"><input type="checkbox" name="r_name" />Address</div>
             <div name="r_t"><input type="checkbox" name="r_name" />Value</div>
             <div name="r_t"><input type="checkbox" name="r_name" />Total</div>');

if($("r_n :checkbox").length > 0) {
  {
         alert("Could not find checkboxes")
  }
  else
  {
      alert("Found");
  }
```

Comment: Note that in your example you use `length > 0`, are you sure you don't mean `length == 0`? Your script would alert 'Could not find checkboxes' when there are some.

Comment: I could nt get that happening.If there are any checkboxes length should be greater than 0.Rit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("r_t").remove();` should be `$("div[name=r_t]").remove();`
`$("r_n").html('');` should be `$("#r_n").html('');`
`$("r_n").append` should be `$("#r_n").append` and
`$("r_n :checkbox").length` should be `$("#r_n :checkbox").length`

finally you have an extra `{` after the `if` ..`
Does it work with those changes ?

**UPDATE**

Finally your logic is wrong..

you say if the length is **>** then 0 (*means that it found at least 1 checkbox*) then show "Could not find checkboxes", but it should really be if length is **==** 0 (*length of 0 means not checkboxes found*)

Comment: Points taken.After removing and re adding it.It is always alerts in if(length == 0)